# SQL adding data into 1 row using while loop

Tags: php, sql

I need to get data into the same row in SQL, I am using a while loop. This might not be the right option. What I need to do is get all the data into one row. The code I have is adding a new row through each iteration. So first row must have data in column 1 through 5 not in a new row (see pic for how it is adding data now)

```
$length = count($row);
$i = 1     
$j=1;
while ($i <= $length ){
 
$sql1="insert into Anser ([$i]) values ($j) ";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);
if($stmt1 === false){
  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
  $i++;
  $j++;
}
```

[image: SQL DB screenshot]

Comment: Not sure if this is just an example, but using numeric column names in a table doesn't look particularly well designed.

Comment: Numeric colums used for example. just easier to work with and play around. Once I have a solution columns will have names with a number at the end. ie. Answer1, Answer2 ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression:

```
insert into Anser ([$i]) values ($j)
```

Inserts one row into the table, for each column.  That is why you are getting multiple rows.  What you want is to specify all columns at the same time:

```
insert into Answer([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
     values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Note that if when you construct the `values` clause, you should be using *parameters* rather than munging the query string with literal values.  This has multiple benefits:

- It protects against SQL injection attacks.
- It prevents syntax errors.
- It allows the query to be compiled only once, which can be a benefit if there are large numbers of inserts.